# Getting parameter values for calling method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, parameters

Is there any way to do that in managed code or at the very least with no serious performance issues? Basically, what I'd like to get is of course something along the lines of

```
public void Method ( int Index, string Name, IPAddress IP, object Arg ) {
  object[] parameterValues = HereGoesMagic.GetParameterValues ( 
    new StackFrame ( 0, false ).GetMethod () 
  );
}
```

but, alas, I suspect that this is extremely wishful thinking on my part.

**UPDATE**

While risking falling into [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), perhaps I should indeed ask for an advice rather than trying myself in bicycle-building industry *again*.

The problem is basically that I have to write a bunch of methods with a variable parameter number, all of which will be calling a single method with a single aggregated parameter. Something like

```
void MAggregate ( object[] parameters ) {
  <...>
}
void M1 ( int i, string s, DateTime d ) {
  object[] parameters p = ???
  MAggregate ( p );
}
void M2 ( string[] tags, float f ) {
  object[] parameters p = ???
  MAggregate ( p );
}
```

Passing an object into those would solve little, as method quantity and parameter variance are quite high. Using copy-paste... well, it's **copy-paste**.

**UPDATE**

All of the above is intended to accomplish a relatively simple task: request various REST API endpoints with A LOT of varying parameters passed as query string.

Required endpoint base Uri and query parameter names are determined elsewhere and are already known by the time M1, M2, ..., MAggregate are called.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a use case and we can help you solve your problem that way.

Comment: Sound a litte bit like http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ?

Comment: Don't try to orient the answers towards some specific direction you have chosen to solving your problem (get all parameter values for calling method without performance issues) but rather tell us more about the original problem you are trying to solve. Because maybe there could be alternative approaches to tacking your specific scenario. If you don't know what problem you are trying to solve then at least you could provide us with a little more context.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme As far as I know, ParameterInfo provides no means to retreive corresponding parameter's value.

Comment: You still haven't told us much. What does `MAggregate` do? This smells like a problem that can be solved via generic method, but I can't really tell because we can't see what is passed into `MAggregate` nor what it does...

Comment: @Erik Basically, it's implementing a number of data search filters. There's a large quantity of differing data entities, and for each varying data entity there's also a large number of different filters. While it's necessary to keep those filters' implementations separate, the mechanism behind them is standard, and implementing that mechanism is exactly what MAggregate does.

Comment: I want to help, I would love to help, but you seem to be unwilling to give us the information we need to help you. As such I've voted to close your question as unclear. `implementing that mechanism is exactly what MAggregate does` **Without giving us any information about the mechanism and what it means to you to aggregate radically different types IMO we can't truly help you solve your problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible out of the box. You could pass an object containing all properties as a parameter an than get every thing via reflection.